# Use a variable as a comparison

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, eval

Given something like this:

```
$comparison = '=='; // it could also be '>', '<', etc
$val1 = 5;
$val2 = 10;
```

How can I use `$comparison` **as** the comparison?
ie. Instead of:

```
if ($val1 == $val2)
```

Doing something like:

```
if ($val1 $comparison $val2)
```

Is `eval` the only option here?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
function compare($comparison, $val1, $val2) {
    switch($comparison) {
        case '==':
            return $val1 == $val2;
            break;
        // etc
    }
}

if (compare('==', 1, 4))
```